# Have you ever been anywhere? Nowhere, but I’m going / No, I haven't, but I’m going

Tags: responses

Are both answers natural? Can I choose freely on what part of that kind of sentence to answer ('Have you ever been'--->No, I haven't... / 'anywhere'--->Nowhere...)?

**Have you ever been anywhere except New York and California?**

> **Nowhere, but I’m going to go somewhere this summer.**
>
> **No, I haven't, but I’m going to go somewhere this summer.**

Comment: The first is not natural. The untravelled person might perhaps complain "I've been _nowhere_!", but I don't think it would ever be used in reply to a question using _anywhere_.

Comment: *nowhere* can't answer your question. *yes* or *no* (or similar indicator) is needed.